# Preemptive Basic Authentication with HttpClient and Cookies

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, big-ip

I am attempting to set up premptive Basic Authentication using the HttpClientContext.  The functionality I am describing below is part of a larger solution for leveraging JWT tokens and F5/BigIP for application and service authentication and authorization.

With a successful curl command and a network trace I can see the following workflow:

1. GET request sent to a URL
2. 302 found on the BigIP instance
3. Redirect to a my.policy -> two session cookies are created (LastMRH_Session and MRHSession)
4. GET request on my.policy
5. 401 unauthorized sent back -> the MRHSession cookie is updated with a new value
6. Enter credentials at command prompt
7. GET request sent to my.policy with updated MRHSession cookie in #5 and Authorization header added
8. Successful redirect

I created in Java code a client context and everything works great with the exception that it always uses the original MRHSession cookie and doesn't pick up the new session cookie value returned on the 401 (i.e. it sends the original session cookie back in #7 not the updated one from #5) and F5 complains about having an invalid session ID.

Below is the gradle reference for the version of the http components I'm using:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.4'
```

The client context creation looks like this:

```
public HttpClientContext create(final URI uri) {
   HttpHost httpHost = httpHostFactory.create(uri);
   HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
   context.setAuthCache(authCacheFactory.create(httpHost));
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProviderFactory.create(httpHost));       
    return context;
}
```